# label with delete button

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a UIlabel that is added dynamically to a view.

What i want is a small delete button (custom image I have) to be added
to the top right corner of the label which should basically delete the label when clicked.

Can someone get me started with what kind of trick can be used to achieve this?
Infact I am open to using any other control in place of label.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Prasad.

Comment: UILabel derives from UIView; thus, you have the ability to add a subview to it: `[myLabel addSubView:myButton];`.  Be sure to set the frame of the button to include the coordinates relative to the UILabel.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks for the answer. The button is not visible. What can be going wrong? I know that it is probably added because I changed the myLabel to myView and I can see the button. But when I change it to myLabel it is not visible.

Comment: Interesting, sounds like some of the label's internals are sitting on top the button.  Maybe try using the [bringSubviewToFront](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW24).

Answer (score 1):

Just make a button and then when the button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)deleteLabelPressed:(id)sender {


[self.labelText setHidden:YES];

}
```